# json array value is not passed back to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

hi i am trying to dynamically validate my registration form, so that check are being made, when the user enters values into input fields using jquery and php. any help would be most appreciated.

html

```
   <DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jQuery Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="fname" size ="25" placeholder="firstname" />
<span id="fname_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="lname" size ="25" placeholder="firstname" />
<span id="lname_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="submit" id="reg" value="sign up">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reg.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

jquery

```
function validate(fname, lname){
$.post('php/registration.php', {fname: fname, lname: lname}, function(data){

        $('#fname_feedback').text(data.fname);
        $('#lname_feedback').text(data.lname);
;
    },'json');
}

$('#fname').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#fname').val() ==='') {
$('#fname_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate($('#fname').val());

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#fname_feedback').text('');

validate($('#fname').val());

}).keyup(function(){

validate($('#fname').val());

});

$('#lname').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#lname').val() ==='') {
$('#lname_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate($('#lname').val());

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#lname_feedback').text('');

validate($('#lname').val());

}).keyup(function(){

validate($('#lname').val());

});
```

php

```
<?php

require '../init.php';
$fname_error= '';
$lname_error='';

if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];

     //updated if statement
     if (strlen($fname) < 5)
    {
        $fname_error = 'example error message';
    } else {

         $fname_error = 'example';
    } 
}

if(isset($_POST['lname']))
{
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];

     //updated if statement
     if (strlen($lname) < 5)
    {
        $lname_error = 'example error message';
    } else {

         $lname_error = 'example';
    } 
}


$return_data=array('fname'=> $fname_error, 'lname'=>$lname_error);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parseJSON function of jquery to use return data, so line will be something like this in validate function

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$('#fname_feedback').text(obj.fname);
```

I controller you need to add like this

```
<?php

require '../init.php';
$fname_error= '';

if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];

     //updated if statement
     if (strlen($fname) < 5)
    {
        $fname_error = 'example error message';
    }
}

$return_data=array('fname'=> $fname_error);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: i think the error is to do with where i have declared my fname_error variable

Comment: you need to add this line below the If condition $return_data=array('fname'=> $fname_error);

Comment: Thanks but if I had a lot more if statements and I kept pasting it under the if statement wouldn't I just be duplicating code

Comment: @percy3872 i modified my answer you can check now controller code in this

Comment: thanks this passes the data back however when i do an else statement for the fname_ error it does not overide what is currently stored in the fname_error variable

Comment: show me the code so i can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: the code works for one input field, when i try and use another input filed by duplicating some of the jquery, php code the first input field is still validated but the second input field does not get validated